# Finding the criterion of the Features in Binary Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, random-forest, h2o

I have done a binary classification using DRF in h2o. I have got the feature importance, then I have asked to find the criterion of each feature.

E.g: I have to classify the user which to accept and which to reject and the features are age, salary, work_experience, live city (already decoded of course). So, my boss wanted to know which range of ages is the tendency of users got rejected or accepted, which range of salaries, which cities that have tendency got rejected or accepted.

I can't be wrong but the output I want may look like:

```
Tendency salary for accepted user = 10k - 50k
Tendency salary for accepted user = 5k - 30k

Tendency age for accepted user = 18 - 55
Tendency age for rejected user = 31 - 35

Tendency cities for accepted user = 1, 5, 10, 23
Tendency cities for rejected user = 3, 4, 12, 36

so on..
```

How to achieve it?

p.s: I have a list of accepted users.

Comment: This seems broad/vague, can you be more specific? See: [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like Partial Dependency Plots.
Here is an example in H2O: https://rdrr.io/cran/h2o/man/h2o.partialPlot.html

PDP will show how the probability of target depends on the value of a certain variable.

Comment: yeah, this is what I'm looking for. Interpreting machine learning models, thanks!